# Android tether/hotspot - redirecting all requests to a webserver after IP is allocated, how?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, settings, wifi-tethering

I've set my phone (Kitkat 4.4.2 (18.3.C.0.37)) to set up a wifi-hotspot using the stock software. There's a simple http webserver on the phone @ 192.168.43.1:80

I can connect to the webserver from a machine that's logged into the hotspot. What I'd like to do is make -all- requests to the hotspot goto 1 webpage that's hosted on the phone instead of having to type the i.p. address in full.

Is there a replacement or a way to reconfigure the routing of the hotspot?

Answer (score 1):

If the constraint is not to tweak your system's hosts file which is the easiest way, then on the device you can run a DNS server. There is a free DNS server app by Icecoldapps on Play Store which was recommended in an answer on AE. But that doesn't really worked for me since it requires port forwarding. My device is rooted, so I used [Servers Ultimate Pro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.icecoldapps.serversultimatepro) to create two DNS servers: 1) DNS Server, 2) DNS Native Server.

Once you have this app installed, create **DNS Native Server** and add your rules like "192.168.43.1" maps to "BCat.com". Then create a **DNS Server** and add the address of **DNS Native Server** in the place of Google's `8.8.8.8`. 
Setting up a server in this app is pretty much straightforward. Otherwise, *Google is your friend for life*.

Now start the **DNS Native server** followed by **DNS Server**.

It should now be working. If you have a Linux machine, you can use the command `dig BCat.com` to check the status of DNS.

All that's left is to type in the URL bar of your system's browser : `http://bcat.com`. Done!